# Add BASS library in Code::Blocks on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, codeblocks, bass

Can somebody help me with adding BASS library in Code::Blocks on Ubuntu? But step by step. I tried many things and I can't do this... I have "bass24-linux.zip" file and what now? Please help me as soon as possible!

EDIT:

I will tell you what Im doing:

1. Unzipping "bass24-linux.zip" on Desktop.
2. Copying "bass.h" to /usr/include
3. Copying "libbass.so" to /usr/lib
4. In Code Blocks going to Settings->Compiler->Search directories
5. Setting compiler path to /usr/include (where bass.h is)
6. Setting linker path to /usr/lib (where libbass.so is)
7. Then going to the project build options->Linker settings and set path ../../../../../usr/lib/libbass.so;

Then I'm writing a simple program, for example:

```
#include <iostream>
int main(){
}
```

And then I see error:

> g++ -L/usr/lib -o bin/Debug/LightBulb obj/Debug/main.o ../../../../../usr/lib/libbass.so ../../../../../usr/lib/libbass.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Is there something in the .zip file? Did you open it?

Comment: Yes, I opened it. There are folders with some examples and files like: "bass.chm", "bass.h", "bass.txt", "libbass.so", "makefile", "makefile.in"

Comment: I will tell you what Im doing:
1. Unzipping "bass24-linux.zip" on Desktop.
2. Copying "bass.h" to /usr/include
3. Copying "libbass.so" to /usr/lib
4. In Code Blocks going to Settings->Compiler->Search directories
5. Setting compiler path to /usr/include (where bass.h is)
6. Setting linker path to /usr/lib (where libbass.so is)
7. Then going to the project build options->Linker settings and set path ../../../../../usr/lib/libbass.so;

Comment: Then Im trying to write a simple program, even:
#include <iostream>
int main(){}

and I see the information:
g++ -L/usr/lib -o bin/Debug/LightBulb obj/Debug/main.o   ../../../../../usr/lib/libbass.so
../../../../../usr/lib/libbass.so: error adding symbols: File in wrong format
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: Please add the code and the errors in your question by editing it (comments are less visible).